# ReferenceError: Cannot access 'x' before initialization in React hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having some trouble with a piece of code in React.

I've created a gh repo that reproduce the error : https://github.com/AnatoleLucet/next-issue

I'm trying to do a hook that gets some local data (in my real app it's a translation system, but you get the idea). Thing is, I pass each "part" of my data (see `data/myData.ts` and `data/index.ts`) in a function called `formatData`, this function is declared in the same file as my hook (`hooks/myHook.ts`). Then when I use my hook in a component (see `pages/index.tsx`) I get the following error :

[image]

I don't understand why the browser (or webpack ?) doesn't initialize `formatData` at the right time...

I'm using Nextjs but I don't think it's related to the issue, although I haven't tried on a "vanilla" React project.

As a temporary fix, I can move `formatData` to another file like `utils/data.ts`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a circular dependency.

- `hooks/myHook.ts` imports from `data/index.ts`
- `data/index.ts` imports from `data/myData.ts`
- `data/myData.ts` imports from `hooks/myHook.ts`

Comment: Indeed. So I have to rethink my design. Thanks